# How to remove the virtually added angular files from the .net core web api project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I want to start a new project using asp.net core web.api and angular 9. As a start, I want to create a .net core web api project without MVC or scaffolded angular project. What I also would like is to start the spa when the web.api is launched, the same way it works with a scaffolded create asp.net core web application (version 3.1) with Angular. I want to use this scaffold as my source, but out of the box, there are some things I don't like about this scaffolded project. The version of the angular is 8, not 9 but a simple update could fix that I guess. The other thing I try to achieve is change the folder structure and replace the angular project out of the web api project.

The original folder structure is:

```
Solutionfolder
  |- WebApi project
      |- ClientApi (which contains the angular project)
```

What I want is:

```
Solutionfolder
  |- WebApp (which contains the angular project)
  |- WebApi project
```

As I believe the angular project doesn't belong in the web api project. To achieve this, I started a new asp.net core web application with .net core version 3.1 and choosing Angular in the proces and then I did the following steps:

- I moved the ClientApi project next to the WebApi project and renamed it (for this PoC I changed it to ClientApiChanged).
- In my startup.cs I changed the following configurations:

  - `configuration.RootPath = "../ClientAppChanged/dist";`
  - `spa.Options.SourcePath = "../ClientAppChanged";`
- And finally, I changed the spaRoot in the .csproj file: `<SpaRoot>..\ClientAppChanged\</SpaRoot>`

And this works but the last step seems to cause a nasty side effect: it adds virtually the angular project files to the WebApi project:

[image]

So my final step is to get rid of the virtually added files but I cannot figure out why it is added. My best guess is it got to do with the spaRoot setting in the .csproj file. My question is: why is the files virtually added to the web API project file and how can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I found a topic which helped me in the right direction. In the .csproj file, the next line is causing the added files virtually to the project:

`<None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />`

After removing this line of code, the files aren't shown anymore as part of the project:

[image]